Doubt on exercise on Von Neumann factor
I am trying to solve the last point of the following exercise, but I don't know how to approach it.The exercise says:
Let $M \subseteq B(\mathbb{H})$ be a type $\mathbb{II}_1$ factor Von Neumann algebra. Let $\tau$ be its unique normal, tracial, faithful state such that $\tau(x) = <\Omega| x \Omega>$ for every element $x \in M$. Let $\Omega$ be a separating, cyclic vector in $\mathbb{H}$. Let $J: \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$ be defined by $Jx\Omega = x^* \Omega$. Prove that

$J$ is an antilinear isometry, such that $\forall \phi, \psi \in \mathbb{H}, <\phi| J\psi> = <\psi|J\phi>$
$JxJ (y\Omega) = y x^* \Omega, \forall x, y \in M$
$\forall x \in M'$, the commutant of M, it holds true that $Jx\Omega = x^* \Omega$.
Prove also that $JMJ = M'$, and that $M'$ is also a type $\mathbb{II}_1$ factor. How does $\tau$ acts on $M'$?

I have been able to prove points 1 and 2, and to prove the first relation of point 3. However, I have no clue how to prove that $JMJ = M'$. Any idea?

First, a proof that $JMJ \subset M’$. Since $\Omega$ is cyclic for $M$, it suffices to prove $JaJbx\Omega = bJaJx\Omega$ for all $a, b, x \in M$. This can be done by a direct calculation:
$$\begin{split}
JaJbx\Omega &= Jax^\ast b^\ast \Omega\\
&= bxa^\ast \Omega\\
&= bJax^\ast \Omega\\
&= bJaJx\Omega
\end{split}$$
Note that the above only uses two facts: that $\Omega$ is cyclic for $M$ and $Jx\Omega = x^\ast \Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is separating for $M$, it is cyclic for $M’$. You have already shown that $Jx\Omega = x^\ast \Omega$ for $x \in M’$. Thus, the above argument also applies to show that $JM’J \subset M’’ = M$. Conjugating by $J$ then yields $M’ \subset JMJ$. Hence, $M’ = JMJ$.
